# Best practice for updating a live mysql database from local test site

Tags: mysql, drupal, local, production

Hi I have an active live website. I'm using Drupal 7 and MySQL.

While the site is live and collecting user info and other updates, I am working on setting up an Ubercart store on my local copy of the website (using MAMP).

I started by copying the live site to the local site so im working on the most recent update.  It may take a while, and changes may happen on the live site while I'm working locally, and I wanted to know:

What is the best way to bring the local database (with ubercart) to the live database without destroying any live changes (new users/articles) made while I was working locally?

Oh let me add I only know how to use phpMyAdmin... don't have the time now to learn ssh, but it's on my todo list at some point...

Answer (score 2):

Use phpMyAdmin's Database Synchronization feature. It not only synchronizes whole databases, but selective tables.

From [phpMyAdmin's documentation](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#faq9_1):

> You can now synchronize databases/tables in phpMyAdmin using the
>   Synchronize feature. It allows you to connect to local as well as
>   remote servers [...] you can now synchronize your databases placed on
>   the same server or some remote server [...] Other than the full
>   database, certain tables of the databases can also be synchronized.

So figure out which tables you want to keep in sync and in what direction, then use your Google-fu for tutorials on phpMyAdmin's Synchronization feature if you've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

One way that might be either hazardous or immensely cool depending on the type of application you're working on is to use `ssh` to tunnel to your remote database and connect your local app through that.

It can be tricky to try and hit a moving target like this, so be very careful.

Keep in mind that whenever working on a production database you should have multiple **backups** before attempting anything like this.

Comment: thanks tadman, unfortunately i don't know how to use ssh, i use phpMyAdmin... want to learn ssh but its not on my priority list atm... thanks tho..

Comment: Not knowing `ssh` is like not knowing CSS. It's an essential thing you should make a priority to pick up.

Comment: Especially if you're using Drupal. It's hard to take the admin side of Drupal as serious as you should without using ssh and Drush. For example, if your site's acting up and you need to get it into maintenance mode on the quick so your site users don't get turned off you would simple run: `drush vset site_offline 1` over ssh in D6, or `drush vset maintenance_mode 1` in D7.